# Aggregate data using the ORM

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Django/Python noob here!

Here are my models:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    court = models.ForeignKey(Court)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Participant')

class Participant(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match)
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User)
    games_won = models.IntegerField()

class Court(models.Model):
    location_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    number = models.IntegerField()
```

My view is currently:

```
def index(request):
    matches_list = Participant.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('squash/base_matches.html', {'matches_list': matches_list}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

My data in the database looks like the following:

```
[match_id] [date]       [userid]  [games_won]  [court_location_name]  [court_number]
1          01-01-2011   mike      6            Queen                  5
1          01-01-2011   chris     4            Queen                  5
2          01-02-2011   bob       3            Queen                  6
2          01-02-2011   joe       4            Queen                  6
3          01-03-2011   jessie    5            Queen                  2
3          01-03-2011   john      5            Queen                  2
```

What I want to be able to do is:

```
[match_id] [date]       [player1] [player2]  [p1wins] [p2wins] [game_winner] [court_location_name]  [court_number]
1          01-01-2011   mike      chris      6        4        mike          Queen                  5
2          01-02-2011   bob       joe        3        4        joe           Queen                  6
3          01-03-2011   jessie    john       5        5        draw          Queen                  2
```

Which means I need to group by match_id. I've tried doing something like the following in my template, but it only aggregates the match_id, date and time. I need to be able to format the rest of the data. In a table structure like preposed right before.

```
{% regroup matches_list by match as matches_group %}
<ul>
{% for event in matches_group %}
    <li>{{ event.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for item in blah.list %}
        <li>{{ item.date }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Any advice here?

UPDATE: I tested with `matches_list = Participant.objects.values('match').annotate(total=Count('match'))` and I believe this is what gets me the aggregation. However I don't know how to pull the correct fields out of it in the template. For example:

```
{% for matches in matches_list %}
<p>{{ matches.match.id }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

This gives me 3 entries (I can see 3

's) but nothing gets printed out. Not sure what I need to do for `{{ matches.match.id }}`

Comment: What is to stop there being more than 2 people with a match_id? How is it determined who is player1, who is player2?

Comment: I don't have any built in controls yet for doing that, so the admin who would enter these would just have to know only to enter two people. It doesn't matter the order of who player1 and player2 are, it would just take the first player and then the second in succession.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest an alternate data structure. Instead of having two rows per match, have one row per match. Then your data structure is basically what you want as the results 'view'. Obviously, winner would be a calculated column/value.

Then your django models can look like:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    player_1 = models.ForeignKey(auth.User)
    score_1 = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    player_2 = models.ForeignKey(auth.USer)
    score_2 = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    court = models.ForeignKey(Court)
    date = models.DateField()

    @property
    def winner(self):
        "None means not played yet, or a draw."
        if self.score_1 > self.score_2:
            return self.player_1
        if self.score_1 < self.score_2:
            return self.player_2

    @property
    def is_draw(self):
        return self.score_1 == self.score_2 and self.score_1 is not None


class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Court(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Comment: Matthew, interesting. I'm not familiar with the `@property` tag? Is there documentation for it, so I understand how it works? I'll test this out and see if it works in the meantime.

Comment: Ok, that's working now. I had to change `player_1 = models.ForeignKey(auth.User)` to `models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='player_1')` and same for player2. Thanks! Only problem I have now is that I want to force it so that player_1 and player_2 can't be the same.

Comment: @name means that name is a decorator: have a google for python decorators. Used this way, @property turns a method into a read-only attribute, of sorts.  It basically means you can call a single argument method (with self as the argument), as obj.method, instead of obj.method(). That doesn't really do it justice, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your table showing 'data in the database' doesn't match your models, so I'm a bit confused.

But going by your models, there's no aggregation needed here at all, since you have a `matches_won` field directly on the Participant model (I assume that's the data you need to display). You can do it simply by iterating through `matches_list` (formatting omitted for clarity):

```
{% for match in matches_list %}
    {{ match.id }}
    {{ match.date }}
    {{ match.players.all.0.userid.username }}
    {{ match.players.all.1.userid.username }}
    {{ match.players.all.0.games_won }}
    {{ match.players.all.1.games_won }}
    {{ match.court.location_name }}
    {{ match.court.number }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Edit** But I don't understand why you're starting from a list of Participants, and calling that `matches_list`. Start from a list of matches, then the above code will work.

Comment: First, I need to pull match id from the Matches model, so I would need to do `match.match.id` instead of `match.id`. Second 'data in database' is a denormalized view of the three models. The logic I'm trying to achieve is very much like how this is setup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773214/using-a-relational-database-to-store-results-from-head-to-head-to-head-gaming/4773458#4773458 So what needs to happen is that for every entry that has Match ID (let's take match id #1) it needs to aggregate that data into one line (so in my case instead of 6 rows, it should be 3)

Comment: Ah, got it. Switched the `matches_list` to `Match.objects.all` That works for ID and date. What doesn't work is the `{{ match.players.all.0.userid.username }}` and `{{ match.players.all.0.games_won }}` Hmmmmm